# Mathematically speaking, How % Completion was calculated on pivot table in Excel

Tags: percentages

I have a pivot table in Excel and I don't understand stand how mathematically it arrived with 70% for the % completion of our project.

There are 32 total line items, so I tried adding the 9 100%s as 9 1's, so 9 + .67 = 9.67/32 = .3021875 then - 1 = .6978125 = 70%. Is that how they did it (there is a link to see a picture of the pivot table below)?

B/c I tried also removing the 67% in Stake 2, so that I just had to add 9 1's (for the 9 100%s) and I divided 9/32 = .28125 -1 = .71875 = 72% but Excel has 63% for the total % completion.

I don't understand, and the internet just talks in terms of Accounting and I can't translate that into what I need it for. Can anyone help? Thank you.

[Pivot table with percent completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awQoW.png)

Comment: Would you be able to read and understand this question if it wasn't yours???

Comment: @barak manos, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You and me both.

Comment: @barak manos, I think this is pretty clearly written. Let me see what other people have to say before I fix it. Also, I would appreciate helpful replies rather than vague remarks, i.e., what about it is not clear.

Comment: For example: "I tried adding the 9 100%s as 9 1's, so 9 + .67 = 9.67/32 = .3021875 then - 1 = .6978125 = 70%"...

Comment: @barak manos, I did that b/c I thought 100% could be represented as 1, as in 1 whole completed item.

Comment: Nevertheless, this statement is hardly readable (IMO).

Comment: @barak manos, let me wait to see what others have to say first. I appreciate your hel and input, though.

Comment: Many other won't bother, and simply down-vote your question (as you can see)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total Nodes Completed / Total Nodes = $308/441 \approx 69.84\%$.

Comment: thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't try that. I wasn't looking at the (2) nodes columns but rather the percentage column and trying to figure the average. Thank you, again!